# Updating a react state using callback function is not rerendering the child component with latest props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have recently encountered a strange issue with react state setter and rerendering of component. I have an object in parent component and I am updating its value using input field and passing the updated state to child component to show the updated value. Now the problem is when I am updating state using callback in setState method, it does not renrender the child component and do not show latest updated state value.

I know the fix just by creating a new object outside updating it and pass it to setState method but I want to know how this useEffect works in background and why is it not updating the state when I am using callback.

I am adding code reference also for better look and understanding.

**[CODESANDBOX LINK WITH EXAMPLE](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-concepts-xj4dvj?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsow3vcj00063b6h1yuozixj%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsow3vci00023b6h7v7hewa9%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsow3vcj00033b6hoxuz3l4v%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsow3vcj00053b6haujxrnbh%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clsow3vci00023b6h7v7hewa9%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsow3vci00023b6h7v7hewa9%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%257D%252C%2522clsow3vcj00053b6haujxrnbh%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsow3vcj00043b6hd9mg0adu%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A0%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsow3vcj00053b6haujxrnbh%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clsow3vcj00043b6hd9mg0adu%2522%257D%252C%2522clsow3vcj00033b6hoxuz3l4v%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsow3vcj00033b6hoxuz3l4v%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)**

Although I added the working link of CodeSandbox which illustrate the issue, I am explicitly adding code here also:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import Heading from "./components/Heading";
import "./styles.css";

    export default function App() {
      const [data, setData] = useState({});
    
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <h1>{data.label}</h1>
          <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Enter value"
            onChange={(e) =>
              setData((prevState) => {
                prevState.label = e.target.value;
                return prevState;
              })
            }
          />
          <Heading data={data.label} />
        </div>
      );
    }

    export default function Heading({ data }) {
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <h1>{data}</h1>
          <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
onChange={(e) =>
          setData((prevState) => {
            prevState.label = e.target.value;
            return prevState;
          })
        }
```

You're keeping the original object in the setState, "PrevSTate".  React only does shallow diffing of what's in a settor, not a deep diff.  This should instead `return { ...prevState, label: e.target.value };` to create a new reference.